# Any way of achieving the same thing as python -mpdb from inside the script?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Besides wrapping all your code in `try` `except`, is there any way of achieving the same thing as running your script like `python -mpdb script`? I'd like to be able to see what went wrong when an exception gets raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to modify the source then yOu could run it from [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) - an enhanced interactive python shell.

e.g. run ipython then execute `%pdb on` to enable post-mortem debugging.  `%run scriptname` will then run the script and automatically enter the debugger on any uncaught exceptions.

Alternatively `%run -d scriptname` will start the script in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

```
python -i script
```

will leave you in the interactive shell when an exception gets raised; then

```
import pdb
pdb.pm()
```

will put you into the post-mortem debugger so you can do all the usual debugging things.

This should work as long as your script does not call sys.exit. (Which scripts should never do, because it breaks this very useful technique! as well as making them harder to write tests for.)

Answer (score -1):

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: Yeah, but this will stop at the line with `pdb.set_trace`. I want it to automatically stop when an exception gets raised.

Comment: You could try using pdb.post_mortem (also in that doc). Pass it the exception's traceback. You'll have to catch it somewhere to do this, of course.